# Insert a list into sqlite which is fetched from a remote database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How can I insert a list of data into `SQLite` which is fetched from a remote database? Also I want to list out these data during offline mode. What is the easiest method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a ContentProvider (in most cases it ends up necessary)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Or use the SQLiteDatabase and SQLiteOpenHelper classes:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Or the ORMLite library:

http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

Answer (score 0):

the best way is, i have the same thing as you. from an api i will get thousands of xml and need it to store in 3 tables of a database. it will happen when i launch the app. for the best practice i will do the fetching data from api and storing it in 3 tables in Async Task as follows:

```
  do in background(){
    do your fetching data from remote
    store in db.
  }
```